# Using a .x file mesh with textures is overwriting other objects colours?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9, .x

Im currently writing a puzzle game in c++ directX 9. Not much of it has been a problem however some of my .x files that I am using (using a mesh class that reads them in etc) seems to overwrite the colours of other stuff.

For example I have a green floor and a white pointer, on a level that has a Diglett looking character that has been made in 3ds and textured then exported to .x using panda plugin, other items that are unrelated start to change colour, the green floor is now a lot darker and the white pointer is brown?

Anyone have any ideas? not sure if its texture overflow or something?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation given the information here is that the mesh is changing some state (such as: shaders, diffuse color render/stage states, etc.) when it is drawn. Then your other geometry is affected by those states. You should make sure that any state your geometry depends on is set to what you want it to be before rendering to avoid it being affected by previously changed state.